# Does anyone know if IE 'return false'?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This simple test code works in all browsers except IE (tested in IE8):

```
#dBox {
    height:100px;
    width: 230px;   
    overflow-y:auto;    
}

$(function () { 
    $('#s').focus(function(){  
        $(this).after('<ul id="dBox"></ul>');  
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) $('#dBox').append('<li>'+i+'</li>');
    });
    $('#dBox').live('mousedown',function(event) {  
        //event.stopPropagation();  
        //event.preventDefault();  
        //console.log  (event.isDefaultPrevented());  
        //event.stopImmediatePropagation();  
        return false;   
     });  
    $('#s').blur(function () { $('#dBox').remove();  });
});     
<input type="text" id="s"/>
```

I've tried all the options from live fn., but no luck.
On `event.isDefaultPrevented()` it returns true, but `#dBox` it's still removed.
I've even tried to bind a regular mousedown inside the focus fn. But the same result it's working in all browsers but not IE.
Does anyone have any idea of what's wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The code you have posted will not actually work. You're passing a loose blob of JavaScript to `$('#s').focus()`. Is this your actual code?

Comment: the actual code it's much more complicated, but I've tested exactly  the above code in a separate file to see maybe I could track the prb., but no luck so far.

Comment: That code would generate syntax errors, @silversky.  I think you're missing a `function() {` at that `.focus` line.

Comment: yes your're right, it was a typo, but this it's not the prb because on my code I've the function () {}. (I've made the change in this example also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is directly because of Event Delegation with [jQuery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) binding events using live does not bind the direct element.  Instead it attaches a handler on the root node of the document.

> The .live() method is able to affect
>   elements that have not yet been added
>   to the DOM through the use of event
>   delegation: a handler bound to an
>   ancestor element is responsible for
>   events that are triggered on its
>   descendants. The handler passed to
>   .live() is never bound to an element;
>   instead, .live() binds a special
>   handler to the root of the DOM tree.
>   In our example, when the new element
>   is clicked, the following steps occur:

Assuming you want to keep focus on the input when the #dBox element is clicked this will work and here is a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/WurDE/) http://www.jsfiddle.net/WurDE/

Note: if you do not want to retain focus on the input then remove the `trigger('focus')` from the code.

```
$(function () {
    $('#s').focus(function(){
        if (!$('#dBox').length) {
          var $dbox = $('<ul id="dBox"></ul>');
          for (i=0;i<10;i++) $dbox.append('<li>'+i+'</li>');
          $(this).after($dbox);
          $dbox.bind("mousedown", function() {
            $('#s').unbind('blur')
          });
          $dbox.bind("mouseup", function() {
            $('#s').bind('blur', function () {
              $('#dBox').remove();  
            }).trigger('focus');
          });
        }
    });

    $('#s').bind('blur', function () {
      $('#dBox').remove();  
    });
});
```

Comment: @silversky...sorry about that...I m not sure what happened to my post but I reposted with a demo.

Comment: Probably you tested the demo in FF. And I know it's working. BUT I've just tested the demo in all the other browsers and and it's not working except FF. The problem is that mouseup will not fire.  I've tried the same thing like in your demo unbind on mousedown AND then bind on mouseup BUT with live fn. (outside the focus fn.). And the same prb. mouseup it's not fired (except FF). I thought that the prb it's because live, but after your demo I guess that the prb with mouseup it's a different one.

Comment: In fact for FF it's not even necessary to write the mousedown fn. or return false. I don't know if it's a bug in FF, but it's quite clever.

Comment: @silversky.  I just tested in IE 8 and Safari 5 and it was working fine.  Not sure what your expierencing

Comment: @John Hartsock I also done few more test. And the prb with mouseup it's only if you click on scrollbar. If you click anywhere on the 'ul' mouseup will fire but not on scrollbar, (it will fire only in FF). The efect has to be exactly the oposite: when the user clicks on scrollbar, the 'ul' doesn't have to be removed, AND when the user clicks on a 'li' the 'ul' has to be removed because that means that he made a selection. With retun false in mousedown fn. it works in all brow. except IE. With rebind on mouseup will work only in FF

Comment: @silversky ..wrap the ul tag in a div and then bind the events on the div instead of the ul

Comment: @John Hartsock I've tried to replace the ul with div and li with p AND it didn't worked. But I'll try this suggestion also

Comment: @John Hartsock For you worked ? In my test didn't. I've tried to wrap the ul dinamically or to place the div in the original html and neither worked. In fact it seems that mouseup will not fire on scrollbar even that the elements are placed from the begining on the doc. (except FF)

Comment: @silversky ...then your best bet it probably to bind the onScroll event the same way the mouse up event was used.

Comment: @John Hartsock scroll will fire on mouse wheel scrolling also, plus i think scroll doesn't work with live, plus will fire multiple times. I've used mouseleave from ul. And all this trouble because of IE. I hate IE. Thank you very much for your help.