# Mouseup bug in all browsers except Firefox?

Tags: jquery, mouse, scrollbar, live

Mouseup doesn't fire on scroll bar for elements dynamically added (except Firefox):

**CSS:**

```
#dBox {
    height: 100px;
    width: 230px;
    overflow - y: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

`<input type="text" id="s">`

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#s').focus(function() {
        var $dbox = $('<ul id="dBox"></ul>');
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) $dbox.append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
        $(this).after($dbox);
        $dbox.bind("mouseup", function() {
            alert('in: ');
            //console.log ('in: ');  
        });
    });
});
// OR LIKE THIS
$('#s').focus(function() {
    var $dbox = $('<ul id="dBox"></ul>');
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) $dbox.append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
    $(this).after($dbox);

});
$('#dBox').live("mouseup", function() {
    alert('in: ');
    //console.log ('in: ');  
});
```

If you click anywhere on the `ul` will fire BUT not on scroll bar. The same problem exists in all browsers except Firefox.

If you replace 'mouseup' with 'mousedown' will fire on scroll bar also, in all browsers.

After few more tests it seems that it doesn't make a difference if the 'ul' it's added dinamically or not, the mouseup just doesn't seem to recognize the scrollbar as part of 'ul' (except FF).

And the same problem if you replace 'ul' with 'div' and 'li' with 'p'.
`<div id="dBox" class="" ><p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p><p>5</p><p>6</p><p>7</p><p>8</p><p>9</p></div>`

`$('#dBox').mouseup(function () {alert ('in: ');});`

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get IE to trigger the mouseup event. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @InvisibleBacon I just whant to do a simple popup select list. But IE doesn't return false on 'mousedown'. So I've tried to do a hack: to unbind blur on 'mousedown' and to bind again the blur on 'mouseup'. But I've discovered that mouseup will not fire on scrollbar in all brow (except FF): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140317/does-anyone-know-if-ie-return-false

Comment: After few more tests it seems that mouseup doesn't fire on scrollbar even if the ul and li are placed on the original doc. (except FF)

Answer (score 3):

Yup.  Here's the open bug on Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=14204

And on webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25811 and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40648

Here's a condescending "you don't need it" response from Microsoft: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxjscript/thread/3749b8a1-53ef-48fe-be81-b2df39d6154f/

That last thread brings up the possibility of using onscroll as a substitute for onmouseup.  This may be a partial workaround.