# Capture MouseUp event of window scrollbar using jquery

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I'm trying to find a solution to capture the mouse up (scroll End) event on a whole window scrollbar.
but this code works only sporadic. any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var scrollTimer;
        var isMouseDown = false;

        $(window)
            .mousedown(function(event) {
                clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
                isMouseDown = true;
            })
            .mouseup(function(event) {
                isMouseDown = false;
            })
            .scroll(function (event) {
                clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
                scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    if (! isMouseDown) {
                        console.log('UP');
                    }
                }, 500);
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
$(document).bind("scrollstop", function() {
   alert("Scrolling has stopped");
});

$(document).bind("scrollstart", function() {
  alert("Scrolling started");
});
```

Here is a link to the jquery library I used:

http://james.padolsey.com/demos/scrollevents/scroll-startstop.events.jquery.js

Comment: nice plugin. but it would still trigger if the mouse is down and not scrolling. the question was to capture the mouseup event. this may be needed in the rare situation you want to add some scroll effect of your own after scrolling, but not as long as the user is 'holding' the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kyyn8/5/

You were close, you just needed to do:

```
if (isMouseDown) // instead of !isMouseDown
```

Comment: it doesn't still work, there must be another way to do it. ofcourse the solution of @ews2001 looks elegant.

Comment: and linking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145402/mouseup-bug-in-all-browsers-except-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Since the browsers I tested do receive mouseenter events as soon as you leave the scrollbar, I tied mouseenter, when scrolling, once, to a mouseup event. something like this:

```
$(window).on('mousedown.ss',function(ev) { 
    $.ssMouseDown=true;
});
$(window).on('mouseup.ss',function(ev) { 
    $.ssMouseDown=false;
});
$(window).on('scroll.ss',function(ev) { 
    if ($.ssMouseDown) {
        $(window).off('mouseenter.ss');
        $(window).one('mouseenter.ss',function(ev) { 
            $.ssMouseDown=false;
        });
    }                   
});
```

which is not necessarily completely true but did the job ...